# MongoDB Aggregation pipeline: group array elements by a field without knowing the field value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a collection of football matches shaped this way:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("SomeUniqueMatchID"),
  players: [
    { team: "Arsenal", name: "Saka", distanceRan: 8590},
    { team: "Arsenal", name: "Aubameyang", distanceRan: 9230}
    // ...remaining players for both teams
  ],
  timestamp: 129380193,
  // other match info
}
```

I want to query for the average distance ran by Aubameyang and Saka when playing together, **regardless of the team they are in, as long as they are playing in the same**.

I understand as far `$unwind` on the players field, then `$match` and finally using `$group` to calculate the average, but I have no clue what to write on the $match condition when I don't know the team before running the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query1

- unwind players
- match to keep only the 2 players names
- group by `match_id` `team` and push the distances in an array
- match and keep only arrays of size =2
  (**this is the key**, size=2 only if those players played both in the same match and in the same team)
  (if you see on the example code id=2,id=3 are ignored because those players never played both in the same match and same team)
- uwnind distances (here we know that all those are valid ones)
- group by `null`(all collection 1 group) and average the distance
  (you don't care about what match, what team or which player, so only information about the avgDistance is kept)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70187205)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$unwind": {"path": "$players"}},
  {"$match": 
    {"$expr": 
      {"$or": 
        [{"$eq": ["$players.name", "Saka"]},
          {"$eq": ["$players.name", "Aubameyang"]}]}}},
  {"$group": 
    {"_id": {"_id": "$_id", "team": "$players.team"},
      "distances": {"$push": "$players.distanceRan"}}},
  {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$size": "$distances"}, 2]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$distances"}},
  {"$group": {"_id": null, "avgDistanceRan": {"$avg": "$distances"}}},
  {"$unset": ["_id"]}])
```

Query2

- local it uses reduce, and the fact that 1 player in 1 match, max 1 time and max in 1 team (query1 works even if this wasn't true)
- reduce to keep those 2 distances, we add on distance array only if team is the same, and the name is one of the two
- again keep only distance count=2 (to make sure both players in the same match on the same team)
- unwind and group by null,average like above

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UTmqalUvBo0)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"players": 
      {"$reduce": 
        {"input": "$players",
          "initialValue": {"team": null, "distances": []},
          "in": 
          {"$cond": 
            [{"$and": 
                [{"$or": 
                    [{"$eq": ["$$this.name", "Saka"]},
                      {"$eq": ["$$this.name", "Aubameyang"]}]},
                  {"$or": 
                    [{"$eq": ["$$value.team", null]},
                      {"$eq": ["$$value.team", "$$this.team"]}]}]},
              {"team": "$$this.team",
                "distances": 
                {"$concatArrays": 
                  ["$$value.distances", ["$$this.distanceRan"]]}},
              "$$value"]}}}}},
  {"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$size": "$players.distances"}, 2]}}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$players.distances"}},
  {"$group": 
    {"_id": null, "avgdistanceRan": {"$avg": "$players.distances"}}},
  {"$unset": ["_id"]}])
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I meant and it was just as beyond my understanding as I feared it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand what you are looking for, but if this is wrong, please let me know.

You should be able to use the aggregation pipeline for this, as you stated, with $match, $avg, and $group.

You may check out a [live demo of the query here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1oMX29gV7L4).

#### Database

If we have the following database structure...

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("123456789101819202122232"),
    players: [
      {
        team: "Arsenal",
        name: "Saka",
        distanceRan: 8590
      },
      {
        team: "Arsenal",
        name: "Aubameyang",
        distanceRan: 9230
      }
    ],
    timestamp: 129380193,
    
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("123456789101819202999999"),
    players: [
      {
        team: "Arsenal",
        name: "Saka",
        distanceRan: 7777
      },
      {
        team: "NotArsenal",
        name: "Aubameyang",
        distanceRan: 9999
      }
    ],
    timestamp: 129399999,
    
  }
]
```

#### Query

We can use the following query to calculate the average.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$players"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          "players.name": "Saka",
          "players.team": "Arsenal"
        },
        {
          "players.name": "Aubameyang",
          "players.team": "Arsenal"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      averageDistanceRan: {
        $avg: "$players.distanceRan"
      },
      "players": {
        $push: "$players"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$size": "$players"
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      averageDistanceRan: 1
    }
  }
])
```

#### Result

Which will give us...

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("123456789101819202122232"),
    "averageDistanceRan": 8910
  }
]
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this doesn't take care of a condition I put which is that the players must be playing in the same team during a match. This seems to get the average distance for the players regardless of whether they are playing together or not, I only want it from matches where they are playing in the same team.

Comment: @DoHn sorry about that! I have updated my answer with (what I hope) is what you are looking for. My fault.